# Is it possible to project sub arrays and retrieve them as one array?

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, projection

From the mongo sample let's say we have a collection like this;

```
{ "_id" : 1, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 70, 87, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 90, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 85, 100, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 79, 85, 80 ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 88, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 95, 90, 96 ] }
```

and then the query is like this;

```
db.students.find( { semester: 1, grades: { $gte: 85 } },
                  { "grades.$": 1 } )
```

which results to this ;

```
{ "_id" : 1, "grades" : [ 87 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "grades" : [ 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "grades" : [ 85 ] }
```

I would like to have a result like ;

```
{"grades": [87, 90, 85]}
```

on one array.

c# code I implemented gives me array of LogLists, code is different then above but the operation is quite the same ;

```
 var result = collectionServerName.Find(x => x.LogList.Any(p => p.Ip.Contains("192")))
     .Project(Builders<ServerName>.Projection.Exclude("_id").Include("LogList"))
     .ToList();
```

I have tried following code;

```
var result = collectionServerName.Find(x => x.LogList.Any(p => p.Ip.Contains("192"))).Project(t => t.LogList.SelectMany(k => k)).ToList();
```

but it gives me following compile error for **SelectMany**

```
The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
```

If I use only Select ;

```
var result = collectionServerName.Find(x => x.LogList.Any(p => p.Ip.Contains("192"))).Project(t => t.LogList.Select(k => k)).ToList();
```

The results type is `List<IEnumarable<Log>>` which I dont intend to have

The reason why I need as one array is I have to paginate the results before retrieving them. I am using c#. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `.SelectMany(...)`.

Comment: I can´t see any code where you´re using `SelectMay`. Please include all information needed to reproduce your issue *into your question*. It´s particulary hard to get what you mean when the comments and your actual code and the exeptions/errors differ on any revision of your question.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this one for c# ?

For all grades in one Enumerable

collection
   .AsQueryable()
   .SelectMany(x => x.grades);

And for paging just add Skip(10), Take(10) extension methods.